# Ignoring delay when a key is held down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Checked out other posts, no help...

I'm using asdw to move an object around within a limited space.  I'm trying to figure out how to allow the object to move around while the key is pressed, without the momentary delay at the beginning.

Thanks...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var longitude = 0;
    var latitude = 0;

    $('body#sense').keypress(function(){
        if(event.which == 65 || event.which == 97){
            // Left
            if(longitude != 0){
                longitude = longitude + 10;
                $('img#map').css('margin-left', longitude);
            }
        }
        else (event.which == 68 || event.which == 100){
            // Right
            if(longitude > -200){
                longitude = longitude - 10;
                $('img#map').css('margin-left', longitude);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The web page

```
    <body id="sense">

<h2><center>Use your 'asdw' keys to move the map around</center></h2>

<div id="box">

<img id="map" src="http://www.toronto.ca/culture/victoria-square/images/ch0/Victoria-Square-map-t.gif" alt="" />


</div>

</body>
```

The  holding the image has a set width and height, both smaller than the image.  The  is set to overflow:hidden, so the javascript moves the image around within the div so different parts are visible.

The CSS

```
div#box {
    margin:0px auto;
    width:225px;
    height:225px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

div#box img {

}
```

Comment: Um, what do you mean?  Which html, of the object or the whole page?

Comment: the object; I'm not sure how it's suppsoed to work.  Show the map and sense id objects in their context

Comment: Hope that helps; if it's not good I'll just throw in the address.

Comment: what's your css for the objects?

Comment: Added.  The image itself doesn't take css until it's moved.

Comment: Understood.  I would recommend using animate instead of css.  That might be the glitchy part.  I tested your code with css, and I couldn't stop the delay.  Good luck!

Comment: P.S. using `$("#sense")` is better and faster than `$("body#sense")` and generates the same outcome.

Comment: thanks, very much, to you both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the keyDown event and then start your own timer interval to control your own repeat interval (ignore the system repeat interval) and then cancel the timer on keyUp.  Ignore the other key events.  You can pick your own repeat time in the setInterval calls.

```
var timer = null;

function increaseLongitude() {
    // your code here
}

function decreaseLongitude() {
    // your code here
}

$("#sense").keyDown(function(e) {
    if (!timer) {
        if (e.which == 65 || e.which == 97) {
            timer = setInterval(increaseLongitude, 100);
            increaseLongitude();
        } else if (e.which == 68 || e.which == 100) {
            timer = setInterval(decreaseLongitude, 100);
            decreaseLongitude();
        }
    }
});

$("#sense").keyUp(function(e) {
    if (timer) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll plug this in and mod it, see what happens

Comment: Not quite, but this is definitely helping me head in a different direction on some other stuff.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `keydown` event instead

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this version of your code. it can be done with 'keydown' event. I believe this is the ideal way it should be done.

http://jsfiddle.net/valllabh/yFxDN/10/

Comment: Thanks, but even in that display, the delay is happening.  Really cool tool, though.