# javafx avoid pause at the beginning when pressing key

Tags: java, javafx

I use the key LEFT and RIGHT to move the position of my view. When I press and hold down the key the view moves to the side, pauses a short time, and then keeps moving until I release the key. Is it possible to skip the pause between the first action and the actions afterwards?

```
gridPane.setOnKeyPressed(
    e -> {
        e.consume();
        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT)
        {
            moveMarkerNextPositionWithKeys(e.isAltDown());
        }
        else if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT)
        {
            moveMarkerPreviousPositionWithKeys(e.isAltDown());
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delay between pressing a key and the key being read as held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24211266/delay-between-pressing-a-key-and-the-key-being-read-as-held-down)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pause you are referring to is the keyboard repeat delay which can be set in the OS. E.g on windows Control panel->Keyboard->Speed->Repeat delay.
It cannot be overridden. You need to implement a timer which starts with a keypressed event and moves your view until a keyreleased event.

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem and it works really well.